# Class '...\Input' not found

Tags: laravel, search, input

I want to implement a search option on my Laravel application, but had this error:Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found, I have tried to add this row at `config/app` like this:

```
'aliases' => [
....
      'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Also at Controller I have added those rows:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

At Route I have added

```
Route::any('/search',function(){
    $image_tmp = $request->image;
    $fileName = time() . '.'.$image_tmp->clientExtension();
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $book = Book::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();
    if(count($book) > 0)
        return view('home')->withDetails($book)->withQuery ( $q );
    else return view ('home')->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again!');
});
```

But still it doesn't work.

Comment: share exact error which you have get

Comment: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found, when I tried to input some txt in textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**config/app.php**

use `Request` instead of `Input`

```
'aliases' => [
    ....
     'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
```

**And your controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

**and remove `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` top of your code**

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, it works!!! :D Can I reply your answer at other question when this problem is?

Answer (score 1):

you have used the class in the controller but your route is never going to one as you are using a closure. so add `Input` class in your `web.php` file. at the top of your web.php file add

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

if you are using any latest version of laravel, the `Input` class no longer exists. so use `Request` class instead

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

you can use `request()` global helper too to get request values.

however i would suggest you to not use closure, rather use controller for logical operation.

Comment: Still same error! Also thank you for advice about logical operation on Controller, I will consider in the future, because Im new at Laravel, Thanks a lot